Anonymous functions don't see external packages in Julia Pluto notebooks
Let us consider the following three cells in a Julia Pluto notebook.
Firstly, we load a package.
using Distributions

Then we can use exported functions in the next cell (as expected).
begin
    @show rand(Bernoulli())
    f = x -> rand(Bernoulli())
    @show f(1)
end

But if comment out one line, Pluto stops seeing Bernoulli. The next cell produces an error UndefVarError: ``Bernoulli`` not defined.
begin
    # @show rand(Bernoulli())
    g = x -> rand(Bernoulli())
    @show g(1)
end


At the same time this code works in a plain Julia terminal.
How can one use package's functions inside an anonymous function in Pluto notebooks?

The error is not reproducible on my device using the same code blocks... Try explicitly rerunning the using block and replacing 'Bernoulli()withDistributions.Bernoulli()`. Maybe updating Pluto.jl and Distributions.jl, and restarting the notebook will fix it too?

@JonathanF. Thank you for the feedback! I reinstalled all the packages and it helped. Somehow I had the Pluto package v.0.19.9 which is newer than they have (v0.19.46 according to the website)

Glad it worked! If I remember correctly, Julia packages use semantic versioning https://semver.org/ , so v0.19.46 is actually the newer version in this case. Either way, it's working now, so good luck with the Pluto notebook.

@JonathanF. I see, thank you for the information and again for testing!
